# "mount" a serial port or USB or PS/2 or parallel port on a local machine over TCP/IP

Tags: usb, mount, remote, serial-port

let's assume I have two boxes, both running some (any) unix variant. I have root privileges on both boxes and they are networked together. I'm using A, the other is B.

I'd like to "mount" the ports for the second computer onto the one I'm currently working on. Thus, A has one serial port locally (/dev/ttyS0), and I'd like to mount the serial port on B locally as say /dev/ttyS1. Or mount the remote parallel port as it was local the same way. Or make an USB "extension cable" by mounting the remote USB ports as local (beyond just plugging in a memory stick and remotely mounting that filesystem)

Maybe I've don't know the magic words to use to research this topic, but from what I can tell, there isn't a general purpose package or program to do exactly this. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is [usb/ip](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/) project which may be what you want.

**Edit:**

And about serial ports, there is `ser2net` package.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. as for ser2net, from the man page: "The ser2net daemon allows telnet and tcp sessions to be established with a unit's serial ports." It looks like this is for networking without ethernet ports.

Comment: What do you mean 'without ethernet ports' ? ser2net is a server it listens on tcp port. Using client you communicate with ser2net and it opens connection to serial port. If client supports it ser2net offers remote control of serial port parameters.

Comment: You are right. I skimmed the man page and it seemed to be a "TCP/IP over serial link" type program. man (8) ser2net teh suck